# bewahren vs erhalten vs aufrechterhalten

Tags: synonym

I am trying to understand the difference between "bewahren", "erhalten" and "aufrechterhalten" when they mean "to preserve by maintaining". My conclusions so far:

- "bewahren" with the meaning of "to preserve by maintaining" is used with abstract/concrete things which are seen as positive or even with some affection by the speaker.
- erhalten with the meaning of "to maintain the state" is also used with abstract/concrete things, but it is neutral.
- aufrechterhalten means "to maintain the state", it is always used with abstract things and it is neutral

A few examples that I have just made:

Dieses Volk bewahrt/erhält/hält seine Sitten. (aufrecht) (positive, abstract object)

Ich bewahre/erhalte/halte meine Ruhe (aufrecht), wenn ich den Anwalt spreche. (positive, abstract object)

Wir sollten die Denkmäler unserer Stadt bewahren/erhalten (positive, concrete object)

Während des gesamten Prozesses hielt/erhielt er seinen hasserfüllten Blick auf den Angeklagten gerichtet (aufrecht) (negative, abstract object)

Einige Völker hielten/erhielten das Misstrauen gegenüber Ausländern bis heute (aufrecht) (negative, abstract object)

Ich habe meine alte Meinung behalten/erhalten/gehalten/aufrechtgehalten, sogar nach ihren Argumenten. (neutral, abstract object)

Are those correct?

Comment: Bewahren impliziert keine Wertung wie fast alle Wörter außer "gut/schlecht" u.ä., deren Zweck die ausdrückliche Bewertung ist.

Comment: @user unknown, das scheint mir nicht so. Wäre richtig und üblich, "Missvertrauen bewahren", "Neid bewahren", "Trauer bewahren" und "Der Präsident bewahrte die Korruption in der Regierung" zu sagen ?

Comment: Missvertrauen ist kein übliches Wort. Misstrauen sollte man sich bei der Mails mit Anhang bewahren, ja. "Neid/Trauer bewahren" sind Wortkombinationen - was ist damit? "Das Volk der Spanier bewahrt seine Sitten und führt weiter Stierkämpfe durch." Ist das positiv? Drückt der, der so etwas schreibt, seine Zustimmung zu Stierkämpfen aus? Muss es ein Stierkampfgegner anders schreiben? Was ist bei Negationen: "Wir sollten die Denkmäler unserer Stadt nicht bewahren/erhalten"?

Comment: @userunknown "Es bewahrt seine Sitten" - Sitten sind generell positiv gewertet, da sie für ein miteinander und für Regeln in einer Gesellschaft sorgen. Zur Negation: Ich habe noch nie "Wir sollten etwas nicht bewahren" gehört. Nicht (aufrecht)erhalten, ja, aber bewahren scheint mir hier doch sehr eindeutig eine positive Wertung zu implizieren.

Comment: @user unknown, Ich meinte "Misstrauen" vorher. Entschuldigung. "Sitte" sind generell positiv gewertet, wie miep vereinbart hat.

Comment: @miep: Nein, Sitten veralten und werden dann in Frage gestellt. Es war jahrelang Sitte in der Erziehung Kinder zu schlagen. Solange niemand die Sitte in Frage stellt, gibt es auch wenig Diskussionsbedarf u. Wortgebrauch. Daher wird vielleicht häufiger darüber gesprochen, wenn die Akzeptanz der Sitte in Frage gestellt wird. Oder die Sitte der Kindesbeschneidung. Oder Karfreitagstanzverbot. Ihr mögt ja jede Sitte begrüßen, egal was deren Inhalt ist, aber dazu seid Ihr nicht gezwungen und ich bin dazu nicht gezwungen und ich nehme mir das Recht raus, Sitten nicht generell positiv zu bewerten.

Comment: Natürlich veralten Sitten. Aber in deinem Beispielsatz "Das Volk der Spanier bewahrt seine Sitten und führt weiter Stierkämpfe durch." bezieht sich das bewahren definitiv auf die Position der Bewahrenden, welche diese Sitte nicht bewahren würden, wenn sie sie nicht positiv werten würden. Bewahren ist eben entgegen deiner Behauptung positiv wertend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're very close with your assumptions. As said, *bewahren* is mostly used for abstract and/or considered positive things. *Aufrechterhalten* is rather neutral, and comes the English word "to maintain" the closest. Also, it's mostly used for maintaining a state of something. *Erhalten* however is pretty similar to bewahren, while for me *bewahren* has a more personal tone with it, while *erhalten* feels more neutral or technical. But this differenciation may only this way where I live, and considered different in other parts of Germany.

So to your examples:

- Sitten: In combination with Sitten I would prefer *bewahren*, but the
  others work fine, too.
- "Ruhe bewahren" is a fix combination. "Jemand/eine Gruppe bewahrt die Ruhe" -> they keep calm. "Ich erhalte die Ruhe aufrecht" however means that I take care so everything stays calm.
- Denkmäler: As you assumed, *bewahren* is used in an emotional context or with a positiv opinion. *Erhalten* would be more neutral. *Aufrechterhalten* wouldn't work here.
- Misstrauen: is negativ. So I wouldn't use bewahren. Except in the use of "gesundes Misstrauen bewahren" where Misstrauen is considered a good thing.
- Meinung: *Behalten* would be the best use here. *Bewahren* would also be possible, but would imply that you're proud for not accepting their arguments, because you think your opinion is awesome.

Hope that gives an idea.

Comment: Thanks! Just one question. Looking at the "behalten" entry in Duden (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/behalten), the meaning which matches best here is "2b. nicht verlieren; bewahren". That is very close to the meaning  2b of erhalten (https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erhalten): "in seinem Bestand, Zustand bewahren". I guess that you chose the former over the latter because "Meinung behalten" is a fixed expression. Is that right?

Comment: bit tricky question. I think in the case of "behalten" here, the definition 1a) is also very fitting. maybe even the combination of both: "Den(/am) eigenen Standpunkt bewahren(/festhalten). "Eine Meinung behalten" isn't really a fixed expression, i would rather use "An einer Meinung festhalten" or "Bei einer Meinung bleiben" (but that expression may be regional). But in your example, behalten fits best of all the words, and it's a correct expression. The behalten kinda gets the meaning of preserve (preserving the state of the own opinion). 
But I'm no professional, so i might be wrong here.

Answer (score -2):

> Dieses Volk bewahrt seine Sitten und Gebräuche.

*Sitten* alone is somewhat old-fashioned.

> Ich bewahre die Ruhe, wenn ich **mit** dem Anwalt spreche.

Demonstrative pronouns (as definite articles often function as) beat possessive pronouns in German. *Jemande**n** sprechen* focuses on the appointment, not the talk itself.

> Wir sollten die Denkmäler unserer Stadt erhalten.

It's about real objects.

> Während des gesamten Prozesses hielt er seinen hasserfüllten Blick auf den Angeklagten gerichtet.

This isn't *aufrechterhalten* but *gerichtet halten auf*.

> Er hielt das Gewehr auf das Wild gerichtet.
>
> Einige Völker erhalten das Misstrauen gegenüber Ausländern bis heute aufrecht.

*Bis heute* requires *Präsens*.

> Ich habe meine Meinung behalten, trotz ihrer Argumente.

*Aufrechterhalten* is also possible.

*Halten* a place means not giving up a position in a narrow sense, for example a real place or a placing in a competition.

> Er hat die Stellung gehalten.

Comment: I'd prefer if you focused on my question and explained in your answer why you did NOT select some of the verbs I proposed in some of the sentences

Comment: "Bis heute" does not require *Präsens*. The meaning is different, but it's not wrong: "Sie hielten es bis heute aufrecht" -> until today, but no longer, "Sie halten es bis heute aufrecht" -> until this day and for days to come.